# Auto-RowHeight in wpf.DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, row-height

I had binded DataGrid to my collection, and i need bind height of each row to my property.

Is it possible? Or is there another way, to link height of each row with corresponding  property in the collection ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can bind `Height` in the `RowStyle`.

Assuming you have a property called `RowHeight`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RowHeight}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```